# grep --exclude-dir behaviour: a bug or a feature?

Tags: grep

I have noticed an annoying change in `grep -r --exclude-dir` behaviour. 
Consider the following test:

```
mkdir -p ./d1/d2
echo 'randomtext' > ./d1/d2/testfile

grep -nr --exclude-dir ./d1/d2 'randomtext'
```

An expected behaviour is that grep would not show "testfile" as it should be filtered via `--exclude-dir`. That works for grep v2.10 and 2.11. However for versions 2.12+ the output is:

```
./d1/d2/testfile:1:randomtext
```

Moreover, the behaviour is inconsistent:

```
grep -nr --exclude-dir d1 'randomtext'
# or 
grep -nr --exclude-dir d2 'randomtext'
```

Work fine, without any output, as expected.

I believe that it is a bug. Can you please confirm my theory? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between v2.11 and v2.12, the `grep` changelog mentions only the following change about `--exclude-dir`:

```
grep: fix segfault with -r --exclude-dir and no file operand
```

I suppose that the change of behavior is a side effect of this fix (which is exactly your case), i.e. a bug has been introduced, but as you can see, `grep` could also segfault in this case before v2.12. So, do not expect v2.11 to be reliable.

I suggest that you report this bug.

Note: This segfault was due to a fix in v2.11. The `NEWS` file says for v2.11:

```
The --include, --exclude, and --exclude-dir options now handle
command-line arguments more consistently.  --include and --exclude
apply only to non-directories and --exclude-dir applies only to
directories.  "-" (standard input) is never excluded, since it is
not a file name.
[bug introduced in grep-2.5]
```

and for v2.12:

```
grep no longer segfaults with -r --exclude-dir and no file operand.
I.e., ":|grep -r --exclude-dir=D PAT" would segfault.
[bug introduced in grep-2.11]
```