# Is there is a way to exclude nested subdirectory specified by a path to that dir from grep recursive search?

Tags: grep, filenames

Or I have to use `ack` or `find` for this?

Here's what I want. Say I have this dir structure:

```
dir/nesteddir/match.txt
otherdir/nesteddir/match.txt
```

How do I exclude first nesteddir only? Is it even possible using grep? 
Most obvious answer `$ grep -r --exclude-dir="dir/nesteddir" "stringToFind" .` doesn't seem to work, nor do any of my experiments with various `--exclude-dir` paths using globbing, leading `./`, etc.

Reading man page and googling didn't help, the only mention of this usecase I found is this question: [grep --exclude-dir behaviour: a bug or a feature?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184200/grep-exclude-dir-behaviour-a-bug-or-a-feature)

It was concluded that this is bug introduced in grep 2.12, but I'm using latest version (2.16) and grep's bugtracker (https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/pkgreport.cgi?package=grep) doesn't mention anything related to `--exclude-dir`, so I guess either it was fixed or it's an intended behaviour.

Would be really nice to get some clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument of `--exclude-dir` is a pattern that is matched against a directory's base name, i.e. the part without the leading parent directories. For example `--exclude-dir=nesteddir` excludes both `dir/nesteddir` and `otherdir/nesteddir` (and their subdirectories).

There is no way to exclude one directory without excluding other directories with the same name using only GNU grep. You need to use a more sophisticated method of choosing files, for example GNU find:

```
find dir -path dir/nesteddir -prune -o -type f -exec grep -H 'pattern' {} +
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, though this behaviour seems strange and inconsitent since other "exclude" variants (say rsync or tar) allow it iirc.

Comment: @Heinlein Rsync, tar and so on are tools designed to work on directory trees. Grep is designed to work on individual files, with recursion support added as an afterthought. The typical use case is things like `grep --exclude-dir=.svn`. For complex use cases, keep using find.