# Make grep exclude a specific directory

Tags: text-processing, grep, wildcards, search

## The context

Consider the following directory

```
$ tree -a $(pwd) | sed "s,$HOME,~,g"
~/mytest
├── 1
│   ├── 1.txt
│   └── 2
│       └── 1_2.txt
└── 2
    └── 2.txt

3 directories, 3 files
```

and the following files

```
$ find $(pwd) -type f \
| while read l; do echo "File: $l"; cat $l; done \
| sed "s,$HOME,~,g"
File: ~/mytest/1/2/1_2.txt
1
File: ~/mytest/1/1.txt
1
File: ~/mytest/2/2.txt
1
```

As can be seen above, all files contains the pattern `1`.

What I want to do is to search a pattern in all directories but the `~/mytest/2` directory. That is, I do want `grep` to include the `~/mytest/1/2` directory when searching.

## The problem

I first tried executing the following command

- `grep --exclude-dir=2 -R '1' .` but it excludes the `~/mytest/1/2` directory.

According to the manual page of the `grep` command in my system, the `--exclude-dir` flag waits for a pattern

```
$ man grep
...
--exclude-dir=GLOB
    Skip any command-line directory with a name suffix that matches the pattern GLOB.    When searching recursively, skip any subdirectory whose base name matches GLOB.  Ignore any redundant trailing slashes in GLOB.
...
```

Because of this, I've tried with the following commands but none of them worked.

- `grep --exclude-dir="./2" -R '1'`  but tt doesn't exclude the `~/mytest/2` directory.
- `grep --exclude-dir="./2/*" -R '1' .` but it doesn't exclude the `~/mytest/2` directory.
- `grep --exclude-dir="$(pwd)/2" -R '1' .`: but it doesn't exclude the `~/mytest/2` directory.
- `grep --exclude-dir="$(pwd)/2/*" -R '1' .`: but it doesn't exclude the `~/mytest/2` directory.

## The question

Which are the flags that would need to be used to make `grep` exclude an specific directory **`(A)`** without making it exclude those directories that have the same name as **`(A)`**?

Note that in the minimal working example, the answer must output the following

```
$ grep {options}
./1/2/1_2.txt:1
./1/1.txt:1
```

## Additional context

I can accomplish that by running the following command (see code below). However, I'm interested in understanding how to do it just by using `grep`. I do want to understand why the arguments (which I've tried and which are patterns) passed to the `--exclude-dir` flag does not cause `grep` to exclude that specific directory. At the end, they were patterns which only match the `~/mytest/2/` directory.

```
$ find . ! -ipath "./2/*" -type f -exec grep '1' {} +
./1/2/1_2.txt:1
./1/1.txt:1
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible with `grep` alone. The manual says `skip any subdirectory whose *base name* matches GLOB`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324608

Comment: Interesting. I didn't give much attention to the `*base part*` part in the documentation. That part and the answer to the question you quoted explains everything. Thank you very much.

Comment: if you okay with an alternate tool, use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), which is generally faster too

Comment: Well, in your case that looks like you could just use `grep -re pattern ./1`. But that wouldn't include `./3`, or `./3/1` if those are what you want to include.